# Bulk fetching from python iterables or list

Tags: python, pymongo

Is it possible to fetching multiple elements from list or iterables at once during an iteration?

I have an iterable object which is actually `pymongo.cursor`. The cursor points a millions of records behind. What I want to do is that fetching multiple elements (or documents, rows whatever) from the cursor.

Below is something like what I want to do with Python. Roughly represented in C.

```
int bucket_size = 100;
int list_len = 1000;
for (int i=0; i < list_len; i+=bucket_size) {
    memcpy(buf, src+i, bucket_size);
```

The point is that this is **not** iterate 1,000 times but just 10 times.

Regarding pymongo, maybe I can find another way to improve its performance but I just wonder if bulk fetching from python iterable (or list) is possible.

Comment: could multithreading help?

Comment: @galaxyan: For performance? Yes maybe it help. But I'm wondering if bulk fetching from python iterable is possible. :)

Comment: try lst[bulkBegin:bulkEnd]